# nodejs mongodb not deleteing based on id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Can you please help me with this code. This code is not deleting the value from MongoDB, while I am running this url : http://localhost:3000/delete/57c6713455a6b92e105c5250.

I am getting this response: `{"lastErrorObject":{"n":0},"value":null,"ok":1}`, but not deleting .

```
app.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
   var uid = req.params.id;
   db.collection('quotes').findOneAndDelete({'_id': uid}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      res.send(result);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Is there any result for `db.collection('quotes').find({'_id': uid})`?

Comment: As per doc `Deletes a single document based on the filter and sort criteria, returning the deleted document`. What you are getting as result is not proper.

Comment: I think you're missing the objectId in your query object: `{ '_id': ObjectId(uid) }`

Comment: @cbass make that an answer, it's most likely the correct cause =D

Comment: @robertklep done!

Answer (score 6):

In MongoDB you query a document id(`_id`) by using the `ObjectId` constructor and not the ObjectId's string. Thus the query needs to be: `{ '_id': ObjectId(uid) }`.

#### Example

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;    

//Include ObjectId
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

mongoClient.connect("Your connection string", function(err, db) {
   var query = {
      _id: ObjectId("id_string") // Important to notice
   };
   var collection = db.collection('your collection');

   collection.find(query, function(err, docs) {
       console.log(err, docs);
   });
});
```

#### Suggestion

```
//Include ObjectId
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

app.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
   var uid = req.params.id;

   //Add object id to query object
   db.collection('quotes').findOneAndDelete({'_id': ObjectId(uid)}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      res.send(result);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you , now its working fine. after adding var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;  and     {'_id': ObjectId(uid)}

Answer (score 1):

Yes. thank you i figured where i did wrong. see below correct answer.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
app.get('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
var uid = req.params.id;
db.collection('quotes').findOneAndDelete({'_id': ObjectId(uid) }, (err, result) => {
if (err) return res.send(500, err);
res.send(result);
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This response means, your query is executing properly "OK":1, but the find query is unable to find any doc to delete it.

So before using "`findOneAndDelete`" use only "`findOne`" and log the response to check weather you that doc or not.