# Having issues with remove function on Express

Tags: express, vue.js

I've recently started learning some backend and I'm having some issues with creating a delete function. I'm using Vue with Node, Express, Monk/Mongo.

I have a page where these card components are dynamically posted to. However,every time I run that said delete method to remove one specific instance of that said component in that view, I keep getting this error message:

```
DELETE http://localhost:1234/tips 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And this is what I see in the Network Logs:

```
message: ""value" must be of type object"
```

And on my index.js:  (sidenote, when I pass '/tips' to app.delete and run tips.remove(req.body) instead of tips.findByIdAndRemove... I end up deleting all instances of that component in that view.

```
app.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  tips.remove(req.params.id).then((tip) => {
    res.json(tip);
  }).catch((error) => {
    res.status(500);
    res.json(error);
  });
});
```

And this is what I have on my vue component that has the delete method:

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:1234/tips'

 methods: {
    deleteMyTip(){
      fetch(API_URL, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.tipObject),
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a tip object as the request body, but DELETE requests aren't supposed to have any body. Your DELETE route is expecting an ID, all you need to do is pass the ID of the tip you want to delete in the URL.

```js
deleteMyTip(){
  fetch(`${API_URL}/${this.tipObject.id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Remove item from UI
  });
}
```

It's also common practice to return an empty body with a 204 (no content) status.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do i do this part?
"all you need to do is pass the ID of the tip you want to delete in the URL."

Comment: Thanks again. Now i'm getting this error:

`[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
found in---> <TipCard> at src/components/Core/Cards/TipCard.vue
<DestinationPage> at src/views/DestinationPage.vue<App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>`


Could it be that it's because I've set up my route to this URL:?

` {
    path: "/tips/destination",
    name: "DestinationPage",
    component: () => 
      import("../views/DestinationPage.vue")
  },`

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your code. Does the component display a single tip? Is it receiving the tip as a prop, and can you use the vue devtools to check if it is?

Comment: Yes, the component displays 1 single tip. The data comes from its parent view DestinationPage.vue that fetches the data like this:

  `mounted() {
    fetch(API_URL).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
      this.tips = result;
    });
  },`

I actually am not able to access its id from tipObject.id. But I have a createTip method that generates tips as objects. From there I can access the id by using result._id

Comment: It it possible for you to post a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/) with the code for your tip component and its parent?

Comment: Sure thing. [codepen](https://codepen.io/juanyeeast/pen/zYrvGag)

Comment: Ah OK, so as you're iterating over the tips like that, you'll need to do two things.

1. Change the click handler on the delete button to pass the tip ID: `@click="deleteMyTip(tip._id)"`
2. Change the `deleteMyTip` method to take the ID as an argument and use that in the URL (instead of `this.tipObject.id`)

Comment: I'm now able to get the tipObject._id and pass it to the URL but now I get this error:

`{_original: "5ede0dad68beb1eb22b909d5",…}
details: [{message: ""value" must be of type object", path: [], type: "object.base",…}]
0: {message: ""value" must be of type object", path: [], type: "object.base",…}
context: {type: "object", label: "value", value: "5ede0dad68beb1eb22b909d5"}
message: ""value" must be of type object"
path: []
type: "object.base"
_original: "5ede0dad68beb1eb22b909d5"`

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to change the method you're calling in your `delete` route from `tips.remove()` to `tips.findByIdAndRemove()`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried a bunch of different delete methods according to Mongo's documentation but the only two that worked were `remove` which nukes the db and `findOneAndDelete` which only removes the 1st document. And both only work when passing `req.body` ie: `app.delete('/tips/:id', (req, res) => {   tips.findOneAndDelete(req.body).then((tip) => {     res.json(tip);   }).catch((error) => {     res.status(500);     res.json(error);   }); });` If I pass `(req.params.id)` it throws the `message: ""value" must be of type object"` error.

Comment: So `tips.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)` didn't work?

Comment: Nope, it just throws this error: 
`{message: ""value" must be of type object", path: [], type: "object.base",…}`

I am using Monk/Mongo and I wonder if I should switch to Mongoose? I just noticed that `findByIdAndRemove` isn't on the Monk documentation.

Comment: I would take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252674/2411156

Comment: I was able to find a solution. Posting it [here](https://codepen.io/juanyeeast/pen/BajommG)

Thank you so much for your patience and help!